# Caret: automatically detach packages once loaded

Tags: r, package, r-caret, detach

I am doing model fitting with `caret` package. One nice thing is that the caret `train` function automatically loads packages it needs to fit the model. However, it doesn't unload them once the fit is done. Example:

```
library(dplyr); library(caret)
train(mpg~., mtcars, method="rlm")
#### Loading required package: MASS
#### The following object is masked from ‘package:dplyr’:
####     select

mtcars %>% select(mpg)
#### Error in select(., mpg) : unused argument (mpg)
```

We see here that having loaded the `MASS` package for the fit gives an error later as it masks one of my previous functions (`select`). Is there an option to automatically unload (detach) the packages that caret loads itself?